# ggplot: How to add a specific number to each box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Code:

```
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(factor(version),p_opens_visits))
  p + geom_boxplot() + 
    xlab(xlab) +ggtitle(title)+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

In data I have `data$counts` that show counts for each version (means if the same version appears 1000 times, I will have the `counts` for 1000 records). I want to add this number to each box plot. How can I do it?

If I add `+ geom_text(aes(label = count))`

[image]

Comment: `+ geom_text(aes(label = counts))`

Comment: @NathanDay that takes really long time and I terminated. Some `version` can be repeated up to 1000 times (meaning `count` is also repeated), my data has 118126 rows. It also showed me an error: Fehler in UseMethod("depth") : 
  nicht anwendbare Methode für 'depth' auf Objekt der Klasse "NULL" angewendet

Comment: It shows each `count` for each `version`.

Comment: Why not include that information in a title or a caption or somewhere else on the plot rather than for each point of the boxplot?

Comment: @bouncyball because I have around 20 box plots on one plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I would create a new column called `version_count` that captures information about `version` and `count`. Then we use `coord_flip` to flip the x and y axes to make the plot easier to read:

#### generate data

```
set.seed(123)
rep_each <- sample(5:15, 20, replace = T)
df1 <- data.frame(version = rep(letters[1:20], rep_each),
                  count = rep(rep_each, rep_each),
                  y = rnorm(sum(rep_each)),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

#### add `version_count` column

```
df1$version_count <- paste0(df1$version, ' (N = ', scales::comma(df1$count), ')')
```

#### make plot

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = version_count, y = y))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    coord_flip()
```

[image: first plot method]

Another option is to create a new `data.frame` that just holds the unique values for `version` and `count`:

#### create unique `data.frame`

```
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(version = df1$version, count = df1$count)
df2 <- unique(df2)
```

#### make plot

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = version, y = y))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    geom_text(data = df2, aes(x = version, y = -3, label = count))+
    coord_flip()
```

[image: second method]

This method requires that you know where to place the `count` label.